# Is there a way to write this database call into a function easily?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

All of the text in an application I'm working on is stored inside FireStore documents, so to retrieve it I use this bit of code

```
db.collection("language").document("kCreateNewAccount").get()
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
           String viewText = lan.equals("en") ? documentSnapshot.getString("en")
                                              : documentSnapshot.getString("es");
           createAccount.setText(viewText);
      }
  });
```

I've tried to put it into a function that takes the document name as a parameter and returns the correspondent string to avoid writing the same thing over and over again, to no avail, any help is welcome

Comment: Firestore queries are asynchronous.  You won't be able to simply wrap it into a function that directly returns the result.  The wrapper function will itself have to be asynchronous and accept a callback function like Firestore query.  (Otherwise you would block the calling thread, which is almost always bad idea on Android.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries are async, you have to use a callback function.

1. Create Interface for callback

   ```
    public interface OnCompleteListener {
        void onComplete(String text);
    }
   ```
2. Create method for fetching text via document name

   ```
    public void getText(String document, final OnCompleteListener onCompleteListener) {
            db.collection("language").document(document).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            String viewText = lan.equals("en") ? documentSnapshot.getString("en")
                                    : documentSnapshot.getString("es");
                            onCompleteListener.onComplete(viewText);
                        }
                    });
        }
   ```
3. Call the method with your document name and specifying a listener

   ```
    getText("kCreateNewAccount", new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String text) {
                    createAccount.setText(text);
                }
            });
   ```